# why sequelize db:create command is not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Here is my current situation.
I installed postgresql and typed sequelize db:create.

Is anyone know this error?

Than you for your help.

[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I have no idea .. It just showed like that. Maybe that error comes up with only windows users. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Now I solve this problem.

That error might be saying "Username and Password are incorrect Or couldn't find your username(root) in database"

Here is how I solve this problem

1. Open SQL shell(psql) - I am using postgresql
2. CREATE USER yourusername WITH PASSWORD 'yourpassword' CREATEDB;
   [image]

3. Go to your IDE(visual studio)
4. config/config.json
5. Match your development environment's username and password with your psql's username and password.
6. Execute 'sequelize db:create'

Hope it works to you!